# How to detect a remote desktop access on my windows machine?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-control, remote-connection

I am on a network from which any machine could do a remote desktop access to my Windows machine using the tool (remote desktop connection). I want to be able to spot when somebody accessed my machine using the mentioned tool.

Any idea where to look to find the history of access from such machines on the network?

Thanks

Comment: Remote Desktop sessions are by default disabled on a standard Windows image.  Have you specifically enabled the ability on your user account?  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 0):

You can find the history in the [Event Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/inside/event-viewer).

You can [open it with](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/6-ways-to-open-event-viewer-in-windows-10.html):
`WIN+R` and enter `eventvwr`

Please find logons under:
`"Windows Logs > Security"`

[image]